# Populating a table from query results (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I would like to fill a table with the results of a query on existing table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(You don't need to match the table schemas)

```
INSERT tbl_name (col1, col2)
    SELECT value1, value2
    FROM othertable
```

See the reference for [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1, col2)... might be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into table_name ...
select * from table_name where ....
```

The target table and the source query must match in number of columns and datatypes

See this [link](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can even create tables this way, though there the column names must match, or the select results are put in automatically added columns:

```
mysql> create table foo ( id int primary key auto_increment, bar datetime )
    -> select now() as bar, now() as baz from dual;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | bar                 | baz                 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 2009-03-10 17:01:35 | 2009-03-10 17:01:35 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```